# Why is kubectl not found when using sudo, but is found when running as regular user?

Tags: rhel, k3s

I used the installation script and procedure found at https://docs.k3s.io/quick-start to setup kubernetes on a Linux VM.  The documentation is a bit light on some details so it's not clear to me why the install results in this situation where sudo is required to run kubectl commands.  The regular user won't have permission to access the k3s config file.  That is a different issue.  For now I just would like to know how it is possible that the kubectl command is found when I run as a regular user, but not when privileges are elevated with sudo.  Here is the output of a few commands.

```
[~]>which kubectl
/usr/local/bin/kubectl
[~]>kubectl get nodes
WARN[0000] Unable to read /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml, please start server with --write-kubeconfig-mode to modify kube config permissions 
error: error loading config file "/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml": open /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml: permission denied
[~]>sudo kubectl get nodes
sudo: kubectl: command not found
```

How is it possible that the command can't be found when using sudo but it is when not prefixing sudo? I did check that the /usr/local/bin directory is in the path for both the root and regular user.